# How to add space before chapter in toc?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I know how to add space *after* a chapter number

```
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip3mm}
```

How to do it *before*? I thought something like `\cftchapbeforepnum` would be available but it is not.

Comment: `...pnum` refers to the `p`age `num`ber, not the "chapter number"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 27 of [`tocloft` package](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) says that "there are the user commands to control the typesetting of Chapter entries". One of them is `\cftbeforechapskip`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{15mm}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip3mm}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Main chapter one}
        \section{Background}
        \section{Methods}
        \section{Results}
        \section{Conclusion}
    \chapter{Main chapter two}
        \section{Background}
        \section{Methods}
        \section{Results}
        \section{Conclusion}
    \chapter{Main chapter three}
        \section{Background}
        \section{Methods}
        \section{Results}
        \section{Conclusion}
    \chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

[image]